# Docplex adding constraint is too slow

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

This is a same question as follows, but the difference is I'm using docplex.

[cplex.linear_constraints.add too slow for large models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810375/cplex-linear-constraints-add-too-slow-for-large-models)

How can I add constraints using indices with docplex?

My code is something like below.

```
x = lm.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

for i in range(l):
  Bx = {xv[j]:B[i,j] for j in range(n)};
  Bx = lm.linear_expr(Bx);
  lm.add_constraint(Bx == 1);
```

Comment: Please show the code your are using for docplex, otherwise it is hard to tell how it could be improved. Are you adding constraints one-by-one or in a batch? Are you sure the time is lost when adding the constraint or may the problem be creating the constraints?

Comment: Sorry about that. Please find the code above.

Answer (score 1):

can you try to add constraints in batches ?

> Adding constraints to the model by batches using Model.add_constraints() is usually more efficient. Try grouping constraints in lists or comprehensions (both work).

Example:

```
m.add_constraints((m.dotf(ys, lambda j_: i + (i+j_) % 3) >= i for i in rsize),
         ("ct_%d" % i for i in rsize))
```

From [Writing efficient DOcplex code](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/efficient.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of alternate ways in which you could create your constraints. For example you can use functions `sum` or `scal_prod`. And you can batch creation or not.
Here is a small test code that illustrates the different variants:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import time

n = 1000
l = n
B = { (i, j) : i * n + j for i in range(l) for j in range(n) }
with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
    xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(l):
        Bx = {xv[j]:B[i,j] for j in range(n)};
        Bx = m.linear_expr(Bx);
        m.add_constraint(Bx == 1);
    elapsed1 = time.time() - start
print('Original: %.2f' % elapsed1)

with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
    xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

    start = time.time()
    m.add_constraints(m.linear_expr({xv[j]:B[i,j] for j in range(n)}) == 1 for i in range(l))
    elapsed2 = time.time() - start
print('Original batched: %.2f' % elapsed2)

with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
    xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(l):
        m.add_constraint(m.sum(B[i,j] * xv[j] for j in range(n)) == 1)
    elapsed3 = time.time() - start
print('Sum: %.2f' % elapsed3)

with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
    xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

    start = time.time()
    Bx = m.linear_expr(Bx);
    m.add_constraints(m.sum(B[i,j] * xv[j] for j in range(n)) == 1 for i in range(l))
    elapsed4 = time.time() - start
print('Sum batched: %.2f' % elapsed4)

with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
    xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(l):
        m.add_constraint(m.scal_prod([xv[j] for j in range(n)],
                                     [B[i,j] for j in range(n)]) == 1)
    elapsed5 = time.time() - start
print('scal_prod: %.2f' % elapsed5)

with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_dict(range(n),name="x");
    xv = [ax for i,ax in x.items()];

    start = time.time()
    Bx = m.linear_expr(Bx);
    m.add_constraints(m.scal_prod([xv[j] for j in range(n)],
                                  [B[i,j]for j in range(n)]) == 1 for i in range(l))
    elapsed6 = time.time() - start
print('scal_prod batched: %.2f' % elapsed6)
```

On my box this gives

```
Original: 1.86
Original batched: 1.82
Sum: 2.84
Sum batched: 2.81
scal_prod: 1.55
scal_prod batched: 1.50
```

So batching does not buy too much but `scal_prod` is faster than `linear_expr`